# Updating associated table with the values imported from a comma-separated file

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, csv

I have three tables:

- Role
- Permission
- RolePermission (link table with just role id and permissionid)

I have a stored procedure that updates `role`

If I am passing permissionids associated with the role to the update stored procedure, I can use the function `[dbo.Split][1]` to split them good.

But after that how can I update rolepermission table?

Do I need to loop? And if so: how?

Comment: What does your CSV file look like? What is the structure of your tables?? What does your update stored proc really do?? Why doesn't that stored proc update that other table, too!?!?

Comment: COMA SEPARATED STRING LIKE "1,2,4,6"

Comment: Yeah sure - but what do these values **mean** ?? Do you have `RoleID` and `PermissionID` in the same file?? **AND PLEASE STOP SHOUTING AT EVERYONE ALL THE TIME !** Unlock your CAPS LOCK KEY....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE [ROLE]   SET
 ProductId=@ProductId,
 [Name]=@Name
WHERE RoleId=@RoleId

DELETE FROM RolePermission  WHERE  RoleId=@RoleId
INSERT INTO RolePermission 
SELECT @RoleId, P.Items
FROM dbo.Split(@PermisionIds, ',') P
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible way you could do this (lacking detailed information about your data - so guessing at times) would be:

- `BULK INSERT` your CSV file into a temporary table, so you have both RoleID's and Permission ID's available (guessing that you have both in the CSV)
- then use a transaction and several T-SQL statements to put the data into the proper places.

**Step 1: BULK INSERT**

You would need to use `BULK INSERT` to get your data into a temporary table:

```
CREATE TABLE #BulkImportTemp (RoleID INT, PermissionID INT)

BULK INSERT #BulkImportTemp
FROM 'c:\yourcsvfile.csv'
WITH
  (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
   ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
GO

SELECT * FROM #BulkImportTemp
```

**Step 2: update the necessary tables**

Now, once you have all that data in a temporary table, you can update the necessary tables:

```
START TRANSACTION

UPDATE dbo.Role
SET ....... 
FROM #BulkImportTemp tmp
WHERE ........

UPDATE dbo.Permission 
SET ....... 
FROM #BulkImportTemp tmp
WHERE ........

INSERT INTO dbo.RolePermission(....) 
  SELECT ........
  FROM #BulkImportTemp tmp
  WHERE ........

COMMIT
```